# Inline SVG defaults to 100% width in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, svg, inline

To use inline inline SVG's with IE (SVG's in the DOM that are also display:inline), it appears that I have to explicitly set the width if I don't want them to have 100%. Is this correct?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ymFit

HTML

```
<div>
  text on the left
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon icon-werks" viewBox="0 0 40 40">
    <title>icon-down-arrow-circle</title> <g> <circle cx="20" cy="20" r="20"/></g>
  </svg>
  text on the right
</div>
<div>
text on the left
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon icon-noWerks" viewBox="0 0 40 40">
    <title>icon-down-arrow-circle</title> <g> <circle cx="20" cy="20" r="20"/></g>
  </svg>
text on the right
</div>
```

CSS

```
.icon{
  fill:#555;
}
.icon-werks{
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
  display:inline;
}
.icon-noWerks{
  height:50px;
  display:inline;
}
```

Comment: What were you expecting the size to default to if you didn't specify it?

Comment: My assumption would be that it would be wide enough to display its contents while maintaining the correct aspect ratio, similar to a div, span, or image when displayed inline, or SVG's in browsers other than IE. Basically, "width:auto." But event when manually set, "width: auto" doesn't seem to work. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FaiJf

Comment: SVG is not HTML.  It doesn't automatically adjust to its contents.  Think of it as an image surface you are drawing on.  You need to tell the browser how big the surface is that you want.

Comment: That makes sense. I think my hope, was that because other browsers do adjust SVG's to their contents (presumably by using the viewbox info) there was a way for IE to do it as well.

Comment: If by "contents" you mean the values of `width`, `height` and, in some circumstances, the `viewBox`, of the outer-most `<svg>`, then yes.  But they are the only parts of the content that can affect the size of the SVG.